# How I can check a Time Input with DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, time, stdstring

how i can check a string for a time:

for example I want to input 12:22 and the program must check with dateTime.

The Programm is in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse`
 and if it returns true, the string is a valid date.

Looks like you want to check for a Timespan and not for a datetime, therefore use `TimeSpan.TryParse` instead.

If you want a specific format, use `TimeSpan.TryParseExact`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784009(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but I get false if I input 14:30

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach here is to not use `DateTime` but to use `TimeSpan` as you are dealing with a time rather than a date.

```
var inputText = "12:22"; // get this from whatever your input is

TimeSpan result;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(inputText, out result))
{
    // handle error
}
else
{
    // everything okay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22(v=vs.110).aspx) as the following:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(timeStringValue, timeStringFormat, 
                          new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out dateTimeValue))
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way,

```
TimeSpan t1 = (Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)).TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan t2 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
if(t1 == t2) // Something as you want
```

Let us know the Output.